# set a zoom option for drawing polygon in google api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I set the rules to drawingManager, which user can draw a polygon after a specific zoom.
for example user has to reach zoom 18 and then the DrawingManager allow to draw a polygon.

```
function DrawingTools() {
    myDrawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: null,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP,
            drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            ]
        },
        polygonOptions: {
            draggable: true,
            editable: true,
            fillColor: '#cccccc',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeColor: '#000000'
        }
    });

    myDrawingManager.setMap(map);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have an event listener for when the map zoom level changes.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() >= 18) {
        DrawingTools();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, This is what I want.